# Firebase Auth createUserWithEmailAndPassword returns "There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted."

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Whenever I try to sign up a new user from the UI by calling createUserWithEmailAndPassword method, it returns "E {code: "auth/user-not-found", message: "There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.", a: null}".
Not sure if it tries to sign in instead or if there is some other issue.

Here is my code for the Submit button on the UI:

```
submit = () => {
    const un = document.getElementById('email-input').value;
    const pw = document.getElementById('password-input').value;

    if (this.pageType === 'login') {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(un, pw).then(res => {
            window.location.href = 'loggedin.html';
            console.log(res);
        })
    } else if (this.pageType === 'signup'){
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(un, pw).then(un, pw => {
          console.log(res);
        })

    }
```

Does anyone have any clues?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `pageType` variable is equal to 'login' even at the signup page because the ***auth/user-not-found*** error code belongs to the `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` method. Add a `console.log()` statement before the ***if*** statement to detect this.

```js
submit = () => {
    const un = document.getElementById('email-input').value;
    const pw = document.getElementById('password-input').value;

    // displays 'login' even at sign-up page.
    console.log(pageType); 
    
    if (this.pageType === 'login') {        
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(un, pw).then(res => {
            window.location.href = 'loggedin.html';
            console.log(res);
        })
    } else if (this.pageType === 'signup'){
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(un, pw).then(un, pw => {
          console.log(res);
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A more common approach is to have two buttons in the same login page: "Sign Up" and "Sign In" and attach different handler to each button.

e.g. call `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword` in "**Sign Up**" button handler and call `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword` in "**Sign In**" button handler.

Having two pages (login and signup) doesn't simplify your UI. You would still need to link these two pages together in case a user has landed on the wrong page.